# pyspark parse user_agents into new columns

Tags: pyspark, user-agent, aws-glue

I am having a problem when trying to parse user_agents. I am using this lib [lib](https://github.com/selwin/python-user-agents) and have followed the instructions from [medium](https://medium.com/@mahadir.ahmad/how-to-parse-billion-of-user-agents-using-pyspark-f57e680727e7).

```
def parse_ua(ua_string):
    # parse library cannot parse None
    if ua_string is None:
        ua_string = ""

    parsed_string = parse(ua_string)
    output =  [
        parsed_string.device.brand,
        parsed_string.device.family,
        parsed_string.device.model,

        parsed_string.os.family,
        parsed_string.os.version_string,

        parsed_string.browser.family,
        parsed_string.browser.version_string,

        (parsed_string.is_mobile or parsed_string.is_tablet),
        parsed_string.is_bot
    ]
    # If any of the column have None value it doesn't comply with schema
    # and thus throw Null Pointer Exception
    for i in range(len(output)):
        if output[i] is None:
            print(output[i])
            output[i] = 'Unknown'
    return output

ua_parser_udf = F.udf(lambda z: parse_ua(z), StructType([
            StructField("device_brand", StringType(), False),
            StructField("device_family", StringType(), False),
            StructField("device_model", StringType(), False),

            StructField("os_family", StringType(), False),
            StructField("os_version", StringType(), False),

            StructField("browser_family", StringType(), False),
            StructField("browser_version", StringType(), False)
        ]))

df = df.withColumn('parsed', ua_parser_udf('meta_user_agent'))\
        .select('*',
                                        F.col('parsed.device_brand').alias('device_brand'),
                                        F.col('parsed.device_family').alias('device_family'),
                                        F.col('parsed.device_model').alias('device_model'),

                                        F.col('parsed.os_family').alias('os_family'),
                                        F.col('parsed.os_version').alias('os_version'),

                                        F.col('parsed.browser_family').alias('browser_family'),
                                        
                                       F.col('parsed.browser_version').alias('browser_version'),

                                        F.col('parsed.is_mobile').alias('is_mobile'),
                                        F.col('parsed.is_bot').alias('is_bot')
                                        )
```

My problem is that, when I call the function I am getting this error

```
Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o517.__getstate__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist
```

I operate in AWS, using s3 as hdfs, AWS Glue for reading_from_catalog and AWS Catalog as a MetaStore. Any tips or help on how to fix this issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: try doing `return [str(i) for i in output]`?

Comment: Thanks but, already tried it but did not work. It has to do something with pickling judging on the error

Comment: @Gerasimos what is the dataframe sample which causes this error? I was able to run the example in the liked medium post without any issue.

Comment: @blackbishop You re right. I found out that, when using GlueContext, for some reason it's giving that error. When using sparkSession though, it works just fine! I assume that, some configs in the glueContext, prevents it from running.